# Why is Black Panther addressed with "Your Highness"?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In *Captain America: Civil War*, there were multiple instances when **Black Panther** (T'Challa) was called *Your Highness* by the Avengers:

- By Lt. Col. James Rhodes, when Captain America, Falcon and Winter Soldier get caught by the police.
- By Captain America, During the fight between the Avengers at the airport.

Why is that? I referred to the [Marvel Wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Black_Panther_(T'Challa)) about Black Panther but didn't get any info.

Comment: In the car ride after the chase scene, he explains that he is now the King after the previous King, his father, died.

Comment: Simple, Son of King of Wakanda, and after the death of the king. Its pretty obvious he will be king so `Your Highness`.

Comment: Technically speaking he is called "Your Highness" as he is not yet King, but is still only the Crown Prince and heir apparent but has not yet undergone a coronation ceremony,  had he been King he would have be refered to as "Your Majesty".

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The Black Panther is a member of the royal family of the Kingdom of Wakanda and the title "Your Highness" is typically reserved for royalty. [see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Panther_(comics))

> **The character is usually depicted as the king and protector of Wakanda**, a fictional African nation. Chadwick Boseman portrays the Black Panther in Captain America: Civil War (2016) and is set to return in Black Panther (2018), both set in the Marvel Cinematic Universe.

Or as it states in the Marvel Wiki that you linked:

> **T'Challa is heir to the centuries-old ruling dynasty of the African kingdom Wakanda**, and ritual leader of its Panther Clan. His mother died in childbirth, earning him the enduring hatred of his adopted elder brother, Hunter, who also resented T'Challa for supplanting him in the royal household.